# Why is the translator disappointed when Flor agrees to stay in Malibu?

Tags: character, spanglish

In the movie Spanglish, Deb accosts a Hispanic man to get him to translate between her and Flor.  The man is instantly and clearly smitten with Flor.  However, when she finally agrees to live in Malibu with the Clasky's for the summer, he is visibly disappointed (even crushed) to translate the words for Deb.

Given that Flor staying in Malibu for three months would mean that she would be very close to where the man lived, why would he react this way?

Comment: I always thought he took it to be a symbol of possession.  Like, she had several reasons *not* to, and in the end she was essentially bought out.

Comment: Bought out with what?  All Deb did was plead with her.

Comment: Plead with her about how wonderful the life of luxury would be for her daughter.

Comment: Did Deb say that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He seems to be pretty annoyed that he got into the middle of this scene. Deborah basically threatens to fire Flor if she doesn't agree to come with them. She's clearly reticent, but obviously doesn't have any bargaining power here.

In [the script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/spanish.pdf) there's an additional line that seems to have been cut from the film. The translator essentially says that Deborah is a terrible and emotionally manipulative boss.

> The Hispanic man translates the last sentence. Deborah and Flor stare at each other..Deborah's next words are somber and have enough body language to transcend the need for translation...the jig is up.
>
> **DEBORAH (CONT'D)** (big decision) *I'm sorry, my friend, this is what I need. It's just for the summer. I don't want to lose you. But ....*
>
> Flor indicates there is no need to translate. A beat.
>
> **FLOR:** (enormous decision) *Yo vivo aquÌ.*
>
> **HISPANIC MAN:** *She'll live here.*
>
> The man says something in Spanish to Flor as she starts to walk away and she is thrown enough by the statement to actually stumble as she looks back at him...then, before Deborah can admonish him.
>
> **HISPANIC MAN (CONT'D):** *I said, "God protect you from that boss.*